# PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories() in 1.1

Tags: c#

I want to add the CategoryNAme ="Processor Information" property in PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories()           There are 79 categories in 1.1 framework but in 2.0 there are 141 categories                                      My question is can i fetch that "Processor Information " property in 1.1 Framework or I can add manually that information ?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no *Processor Information* performance counter category in your *perfmon.exe* (in general, this is unlikely), you can add this category as manual using with [`PerformanceCounterCategory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountercategory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`CounterCreationDataCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.countercreationdatacollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes. Let's create [`% Processor Time`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938593.aspx) performance counter with it's `Processor Information` category. For example;

```
if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("Processor Information"))
{
    CounterCreationDataCollection counter = new CounterCreationDataCollection();

    CounterCreationData data = new CounterCreationData();
    data.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
    totalOps.CounterHelp = "The percentage of time the processor was busy during the sampling interval";
    counter.Add(data);

    PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("Processor Information",
                                      "This is a sample", 
                                      PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance, 
                                      counter);
}
```

And by the way;

> To read performance counters in Windows Vista and later, Windows XP
>   Professional x64 Edition, or Windows Server 2003, you must either be a
>   member of the Performance Monitor Users group or have administrative
>   privileges.
>
> To avoid having to elevate your privileges to access performance
>   counters in Windows Vista and later, add yourself to the Performance
>   Monitor Users group.
>
> In Windows Vista and later, User Account Control (UAC) determines the
>   privileges of a user. If you are a member of the Built-in
>   Administrators group, you are assigned two run-time access tokens: a
>   standard user access token and an administrator access token. By
>   default, you are in the standard user role. To execute the code that
>   accesses performance counters, you must first elevate your privileges
>   from standard user to administrator. You can do this when you start an
>   application by right-clicking the application icon and indicating that
>   you want to run as an administrator.

Comment: PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance is not suppoerted by framework 1.1 . So , My problem is not yet sorted out

Comment: There is no overload of `PerformanceCounterCategory.Create` method that supports .NET Framework 1.1. Do you have special reason to use this version? Why don't you upgrade it with a newer version?